# Angular event that fires after ng-change

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create dynamically combo boxes and the values in the selected values in the combo boxes must be unique. For that reason I am setting the status to 'NotValid' after the value in the combo box is changed. But the value is getting set before the ng-change complete and the selection is empty. That is why I need to find an event that is folowing the ng-change.

Controller:

```
 self.filters = [
     { value: 'Filter1', status: 'Valid' },
     { value: 'Filter2', status: 'Valid' }
 ];

 self.changeFilter = function (value) {
     self.filters.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (value === entry.value) {
            entry.status = 'NotValid';
        }
     });
};
```

html:

```
<md-select ng-model=choice.name name="" ng-change="$ctrl.changeFilter(choice.name)">
<md-option ng-repeat="filter in $ctrl.filters" value="{{filter.value}}" ng-if="filter.status === 'Valid'" >
    {{filter.value}}
</md-option>
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `ng-model=choice.name` Do you need quotes?

Comment: Is it correct declaration? `self.filters = [
     { value: 'Filter1', status: 'Valid' },
     { value: 'Filter2', status: 'Valid' }
 ];`

Comment: It is not a type. It is working fine like that. if I add the quotes is working as well.